# how to findout action taken against Strictmode policy violation

Tags: android, adb, logcat, android-logcat, android-debug

I am new to android and debugging an existing application. While the application is running, I am getting StrictMode policy violation. I want to find out what actions are taken after the violation has occurred? I am pasting the logs.

```
D/StrictMode( 4548): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=68 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=31 violation=2
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1135)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:148)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:425)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:287)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:270)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.common.BlobCache.loadIndex(BlobCache.java:260)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.common.BlobCache.<init>(BlobCache.java:144)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.util.CacheManager.getCache(CacheManager.java:56)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.app.Bookmarker.getBookmark(Bookmarker.java:64)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.app.MoviePlayer.initPlayer(MoviePlayer.java:281)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.app.MoviePlayer.<init>(MoviePlayer.java:142)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity$1.<init>(MovieActivity.java:91)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity.onCreate(MovieActivity.java:90)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2188)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/StrictMode( 4548): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=67 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskWriteViolation: policy=31 violation=1
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onWriteToDisk(StrictMode.java:1109)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.ftruncate(BlockGuardOs.java:101)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(RandomAccessFile.java:626)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.common.BlobCache.setActiveVariables(BlobCache.java:286)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.common.BlobCache.loadIndex(BlobCache.java:275)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.common.BlobCache.<init>(BlobCache.java:144)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.util.CacheManager.getCache(CacheManager.java:56)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.app.Bookmarker.getBookmark(Bookmarker.java:64)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.app.MoviePlayer.initPlayer(MoviePlayer.java:281)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.app.MoviePlayer.<init>(MoviePlayer.java:142)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity$1.<init>(MovieActivity.java:91)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.intel.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity.onCreate(MovieActivity.java:90)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2188)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1236)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
D/StrictMode( 4548):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Goto Device Settings -> Developer options and Enable Strict mode. Enabling this option will flash the screen in red color whenever your app violates any one of the strict mode policies. So that you can figure out.

Comment: I need to know what action has been taken after StrictMode policy violation.I already know that my app violates Strictmode policy.

Comment: You are doing something in UI thread that is time consuming and may throw ANR. So try to use AsyncTasks or Service or separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the line:

```
at com.intel.android.gallery3d.common.BlobCache.loadIndex(BlobCache.java:260)
```

go to class BlobCache and line 260, here is when ocurr the StrictMode violation.

In most cases the cause of the problem is the execution of operations that are delayed as I/O and network operation on the main thread.To solve this consider use an asynchronous mechanism to avoid block the main thread.